# Why is Tkinter not displaying an image created from .configure() inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a project made with Tkinter which involves buttons. These buttons have a command which resizes their images. The problem is that the images simply do not display. They only display if I create the image as a ImageTk.PhotoImage object outside the class and don't interfere with the image in the **init** function. The skeleton of the method I used to do this is like so:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class GrowingButton(Button):
    def __init__(idx, *args, image=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.img = image
        self.grid(row=idx, column=0, sticky="news")
        if image:
            self.configure(command=self.expand, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    def expand(self):
        if self.img:
            self.img = self.img.resize((1, 1))
            self.configure(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img))
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img)

root = Tk()
[root.rowspan(i, weight=1) for i in range(10)]
buttons = [GrowingButton(i, root, image=Image.open("")) for i in range(10)]
root.mainloop()
```

The issue may have to do with other parts of the code (though I doubt it). If that's the case, please inform me and I'll add other relevant code or maybe post a link the repository. This is a just a minimal reproducible example, but I'm completely stumped on why it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning `self.image` doesn't change the button. You need to explicitly reconfigure the button whenever the image changes.

Also, you need to keep a reference to the image that is being used by the button. You're creating two images: one used by the button, and a second identical image is being assigned to `self.image`. The one being used by the button isn't being saved, so the garbage collected is destroying it when the function returns.

The code should be something like this:

```
self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img)
self.configure(image=self.image)
```